# Изменение значения css свойства

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Нужно что бы при клике значение translateX изменялось при каждом клике. Сейчас событие срабатывает один раз. Проблемма в том что я незнаю как передать значение css свойства в переменную...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.znSlickNav-prev').click(function () {
    $('.slick-track').css("transform","translateX(-"+333+"px)");
  })
</script>
```

Нужно что бы при каждом клике translateX увеличивалось на 333px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tr = 0;

$('.znSlickNav-prev').click(function(){
  tr += 333;
  $('.slick-track').css("transform","translateX(-"+tr+"px)");
});
```

Подключи jQuery перед скриптом.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, а можешь еще помочь, тоже вопрос по слайду, нужно сделать плавное переключение между двумя списками...

Comment: наверное вам будет интересна функция animate() jquery

Comment: https://demo.kallyas.net/sneakers-shop/ - посмотрите, пожалуйста, такое переключение можно реализовать через animate()? Просто там при клике на кнопку зададим событие animate() оно уберет один список но мне же надо что бы сразу появился второй список...

Answer (score 2):

Проблема подхода из принятого ответа в том, что присвоение css-свойству `transform` значения `translate` "ломает" другие трансформации элемента (например, поворот).

Есть более гибкий способ. Современные браузеры поддерживают интерфейс **`DOMMatrix`**, который предназначен как раз для работы с трансформациями.
Подробнее о нем можно почитать [например, на MDN(en)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix).

Или, можно использовать такие вот простые классы-помощники, меняющие значение трансформа через `matrix()`:

```js
class CssTransform2d {
  constructor(element) { this.el = element; }
  get matrix() {
    let tm = getComputedStyle(this.el).getPropertyValue('transform').match(/\((.*)\)/); 
    return (tm ? tm[1] : '1,0,0,1,0,0').split(/,\s*/).map(v => +v); 
  }
  set matrix(v)     { this.el.style.transform = `matrix(${v.join(', ')})`; }
  get translate()   { return this.matrix.slice(-2); }
  set translate(xy) { this.matrix = [...this.matrix.slice(0, 4), ...xy]; }
  get translateX()  { return this.matrix[4]; }
  set translateX(v) { this.matrix = [...this.matrix.slice(0, 4), v, this.matrix[5]]; }
  get translateY()  { return this.matrix[5]; }
  set translateY(v) { this.matrix = [...this.matrix.slice(0, 4), this.matrix[4], v]; }
}

/*--------------------- использование ---------------------*/
const ct  = new CssTransform2d($('#box')[0]); 
console.log(ct.matrix.join(', ')); 

$('.btn-move').click(function () {
  const $this = $(this); 
  let [x, y] = ct.translate; 
  switch ($this.data('direction')) {
    case '<': x -= 30; break; 
    case '>': x += 30; break; 
    case '∧': y -= 30; break; 
    case '∨': y += 30; 
  }
  ct.translate = [x, y]; 
  console.clear() || console.log(ct.matrix.join(', ')); 
});
```

```css
.btn-move { width: 2rem; height: 1.7rem; }
.btn-move::after { content: attr(data-direction); display: inline; }
  
#btns { position: relative; z-index: 99; }

#box {
  width: 3rem; height: 3rem; 
  background: #4d4; 
  transition: transform 0.15s linear; 
  transform: translate(10rem, 20vh) rotate(45deg); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="btns">
  <button class="btn-move" data-direction="&lt;"></button>
  <button class="btn-move" data-direction="∧"></button>
  <button class="btn-move" data-direction="∨"></button>
  <button class="btn-move" data-direction="&gt;"></button>
</div>
<div id="box"></div>
```

*(код в примере работает **только** с 2D-трансформом, тогда как `DOMMatrix` поддерживает и трехмерные. Плюс, стандартный интерфейс предлагает гораздо больше возможностей, и написан он не на коленке `:)`)*